# How do I create a function that chains multiple accessors?

Tags: java

I want to create a function where I can chain accessors, but don't know how.

For example, I have a class `A` which has a subclass `save`, and attached to that `save` class I have two methods `B()` and `C()`:

```
class A {
    class save {
       function B() {};
       function C() {};
 }
}
```

I would like to be able to call them like so: `A.save.B();`, or `A.save.C();`

Comment: first off: you should not reach diretly into `A` to retrieve `save`, but get it through a getter. With regards to the chaining... your question is quite unclear. What exactly is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Additionally, that is not java (unless the bleeding edge versions of java have made some interesting decisions which I haven't heard about).

Comment: @BeUndead there surely are interesting features (most notably [JEP 305 (preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305) and [JEP 359 (preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359)) as preview in Java 14, but you are right: this is not java.

Comment: Formatting, spelling, title.

Comment: This `save` is not a subclass of `A`; it is an inner class.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the keyword `static`.  This (roughly) allows things to exist without an instance (or without an instance of the enclosing class in your case).

Something like:

```
class A {
    static class save {
        static void A() {
            // ...
        }

        static void B() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

would allow you to call the defined methods as:

```
A.save.A(); /* or */ A.save.B();
```

The point being that the `save` `class` being `static` means that you can access it without having an instance of the enclosing `A` `class`.  And the methods *within* the `save` `class` being `static` mean they can be invoked without an instance of the `save` `class`.

(As a side note, classes are almost universally given names starting with a capital, and methods names starting *not* with a capital.  Your naming convention will confuse anyone coming to use your code.)